# How do I urlencode with ISO-8859-1?

Tags: php

I need to have a string return `ISO-8859-1` url encoding, but how do you do it with PHP?

If I run `urlencode('åäö')` I get `%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6` returned. What I need is `%E5%E4%F6`.

*http://quick-encoder.com/url/ can return both formats.*

Comment: urlencoding and iso encoding is something totally different. urlencoding is a 7bit encoding (ASCII), whilst iso means 8bit encoding. There is not a simple function to turn any string into an iso encoded string, that does not make sense from a technical point of view. It depends on what encoding you have _before_ trying to convert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the utf8_decode function before the urlencode and it should do the trick.

```
urlencode(utf8_decode('åäö'));
```

Have a look at [This](https://www.php.net/utf8_decode) too.

Comment: It will work well with `UTF-8` input data, but will not work with other types of input encodings. I'm just mentioning this ...

Answer (score 4):

You need to transcode the input string to `ISO-8859-1` before urlencoding it. You can use [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for that:

```
$r = urlencode(iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', 'åäö'));
echo $r; // %E5%E4%F6
```

From your given output, I assume that your source files are `UTF-8` encoded, or at least the example string `åäö`. If you are working with dynamic data you need to know the input encoding.

Answer (score 0):

What needed to be done here is to encode a well formatted string at the type of you want.
so first lets convert with `mb_convert_encoding()` so like this:

```
<?php
$str = "åäö";
echo urlencode(mb_convert_encoding($str, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8"));
// %E5%E4%F6
?>
```

Cheers.